# Recompile Kernel to Change Stack Size

Tags: kernel, compiling, rhel

I need to recompile my kernel on RHEL WS5 with only two changes.

1. Change stack size from 4k to 8k
2. Limit usable memory to 4096.

How do I recompile the kernel without changing anything else but these two items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change only the new values you will need the config the old kernel was build from.

In RHEL you can find this in: `/boot/config-$(\uname -r)`

Copy this file to the kernel source and change the values you want. Use `make menuconfig` for a ncurses gui.

For other distributions: If the config option `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` was set, your kernel configuration is available under `/proc/config.gz`

Comment: I took the liberty of converting it to `$(command)`. If for any reason it is not equivalent please rollback (and in such case I'm really sorry).

Comment: For future reference, you can just use \\` to escape them

Comment: thx Maciej, its the same.

Comment: @Michael: yeah, but \` wont work if you try to nest the tics `bar \\`foo\\` bar`or other variants.

Comment: Strange, it works in comments but not in posts

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert for RHEL WS5 but for Cent OS 5, which is basically RHEL with all references to Redhat removed, there is a nice tutorial at [centos.org](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel) which explains how to build a modified version of the distribution kernel. The procedure explained there will probably work for RHEL WS, too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "change kernel stack size" option is long gone...