# Installing new kernel (by commandline) as side of old kernel and effective configuration of ' menuconfig'

Tags: kernel, install

I need to install another kernel (2.6.34) into my fedora machine (x86) and i need to show the old and new boot up options in the boot menu (both new and old kernel)

I have downloaded the new kernel and i need to compile it and need to build it.

can you explain me the steps for doing that?

I got  the correct steps from this discussion and am having doubts in the steps 6 and 7 in the below link which explains the installation of new kernel.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

Also can you explain the effective configuration of 'menuconfig' and its what it actually aims?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/7426/67621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need any 2.6.34-kernel, you might head over to [koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=8) and try to find a precompiled one for you version of fedora. You can install it as root after downloading all required rpms with `yum localinstall kernel-*.rpm` and it will automatically appear in Grub.

If you need to modify the kernel, it is best to also start with the distribution kernel and modify it to suit your needs. There is an extensive howto in [the fedora wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/CustomKernel).

Lastly if you really need to start from scratch with the sources from kernel.org, you have to download the source and extract the archive. Then you have to configure the kernel. For this, say `make menuconfig` for a CLI or `make menuconfig` for a graphical configuration. You might want to start with the old configuration of the running kernel, see [Recompile Kernel to Change Stack Size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2496/recompile-kernel-to-change-stack-size).

When you are finished configuring, say `make` to build the kernel, then `make modules` to build kernel modules.

The following steps have to be done as root: Say `make modules_install` to install the modules (this will not overwrite anything of the old kernel) and finally `make install` which will automatically install the kernel into /boot and modify the Grub configuration, so that you can start the new kernel alongside the old one.

Comment: I would like to start from scratch.ie the steps are 1) Download the new kernel source from kernel.org and extract it 2) make menuconfig 3) make 4) make modules 5) make modules_install 6) make install              My question is that , don't we need to select the arch(x86) for my machine right?

Comment: You only would have to do anything special, if you wanted to compile for an architecture other than the one you are running whilst compiling. So no, you don't have to select the arch normally.

Comment: OK. Can you explain how we can effectively configure(for an embedded system engineer) the menu config to get all useful packages?

Comment: This really depends on what you need and which system you are using and can't be answered generally.

Comment: Currently am using the distro version Fedora 11(Leonidas) and  and kernel version 2.6.29.4-167.fc11 i686.PAE #1 SMP . I want to get the whole programming(C/C++/java),internet/LAN/wireless/bluetooth,audio support utilities after my installation.(so i need to effectively configure the menuconfig right? )   .Also in this link what is the meaning of step 6 and 7 ?

Comment: forgot to paste the link ..  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

Comment: The kernel does not include any utilities, only hardware drivers. The comments aren't meant as a discussion board, therefore I'm stopping here. If you have more questions, please either edit your main question at the top or ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this wiki page](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/CustomKernel)? It looks pretty much all that you need.

Regarding the boot options, what boot loader are you using? Grub will probably detect your kernel when you run `update-grub` or `grub-mkconfig`.